# How to encode artist name image to audio recording in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I am working for Music app in that one of the feature is recording user voice and playback the same. So far all things are in control. Yesterday I got a thought and straight away I started Googling, the idea is adding artist names and album image to my recorded audio using AVAudioRecorder, But there is not much success  in it.

I also seen **AV Foundation Audio Settings Constants** to set the AVAudioRecorder settings, failed in this also.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use an existing audio tagging library, so after creating the file, you can use it to add the required data. I did a quick search and found this libraries:

- [SonatinaTag](https://github.com/ljsebald/SonatinaTag): It was made for OSX but it may work for iOS (The project state that has very few external requirements). Not sure if support writing.
- [TagLib-ObjC](https://github.com/eni9889/TagLib-ObjC/): A wrapper for the popular TagLib. Seems to be in development.
- [TagLib](https://github.com/taglib/taglib): TagLib, I know is just pure C pain, but maybe is not that hard to use.

Good luck!